# Creating a PowerPoint Spreadsheet from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am trying convert and/or fasten my presentation.

I have found VBA code in the following  [website](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/creating-a-powepoint-deck-in-excel/)  with code modified a little by me, attached below.

Unfortunately, I can not fit spreadsheet and presentation.

You can see white area in the following :

[image: example].

Wonder if you have any solution to my problem.

```
  Sub WorkbooktoPowerPoint()

'Step 1:  Declare your variables
Dim pp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object
Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As String
Dim MyTitle As String

'Step 2:  Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible
    Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
    pp.Visible = True

'Step 3:  Set the ranges for your data and title
MyRange = "B2:BH40"  '<<<Change this range

'Step 4:  Start the loop through each worksheet
    For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xlwksht.Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

'Step 5:  Copy the range as picture
    xlwksht.Range(MyRange).CopyPicture _
    Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

'Step 6:  Count slides and add new blank slide as next available slide number
          '(the number 12 represents the enumeration for a Blank Slide)
    SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)
    PPSlide.Select

'Step 7:  Paste the picture and adjust its position
PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 1
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 1
pp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 720

'Step 8:  Add the title to the slide then move to next worksheet
Next xlwksht

'Step 9:  Memory Cleanup
    pp.Activate
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set pp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will resize the pasted shape at the same size as the slide :

```
Sub WorkbooktoPowerPoint()
'Step 1:  Declare your variables
Dim pp As Object
Dim PPPres As Object
Dim PPSlide As Object
Dim ppShape As Object
Dim xlwksht As Worksheet
Dim MyRange As String
Dim MyTitle As String

'Step 2:  Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
pp.Visible = True

'Step 3:  Set the ranges for your data and title
MyRange = "B2:BH40"  '<<<Change this range

'Step 4:  Start the loop through each worksheet
For Each xlwksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xlwksht.Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

    'Step 5:  Copy the range as picture
    xlwksht.Range(MyRange).CopyPicture _
        Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    'Step 6:  Count slides and add new blank slide as next available slide number
              '(the number 12 represents the enumeration for a Blank Slide)
    SlideCount = PPPres.Slides.Count
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides.Add(SlideCount + 1, 12)

    'Step 7:  Paste the picture and adjust its position
    Set ppShape = PPSlide.Shapes.Paste
    With ppShape
        '.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Width = PPPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth
        .Height = PPPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight
    End With 'ppShape
    'Step 8:  Add the title to the slide then move to next worksheet

Next xlwksht

'Step 9:  Memory Cleanup
pp.Activate
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set pp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Further, I wanted to change the shape of my ppt but it seems that it still doesn't work and error "Invalid enumeration value" appeared. Tried to google it but didn't find right answer.


`'Step 2:  Open PowerPoint, add a new presentation and make visible
Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PPPres = pp.Presentations.Add
PPPres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
pp.Visible = True`

Comment: Please take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour .Try replacing `ppSlideSizeOnScreen` by 1, as you are using late binding that variable isn't recognized.

Comment: Thank you! There is however an error 438 in step 7. The problem is with command `.Height = PPPres.PageSetup.SlideHeigth`

Comment: @Przemek : Yup, my bad, simple typo in `Height`! I corrected it! ;)